# Support library ExifInterface check if attribute exists or get all attributes

Tags: android, android-support-library, exif

The support library version 25.1.0 has added a new feature the `ExifInterface`, which back-ports features added to the `ExifInterface` in Android 7.1.

But how do I check if a specific file actually has a specific `int` or `double` attribute without providing a default value? Or is there an option to get a list of attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ready-to-use `hasAttribute` method, which would be quite convenient, but instead you could use the `String` `getAttribute` method, which returns `null` when the file does not contain the requested attribute.

**Something like this:**

```
public static boolean hasAttribute(ExifInterface exif, String attribute){
    return exif.getAttribute(attribute) != null;
}
```

Unfortunately there is no method to obtain all attributes from a given file.